# Java, Polymorphism, Static Typing and the "QueryInterface" pattern

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, api-design

I'm working on an API design, and there's something about Java and polymorphism that I didn't think about until now. If I create an API like this:

```
interface FooFactory
{
    public Foo getFoo();
}

interface Foo
{
    public void sayFoo();
}
```

then the only thing that my `FooFactory` implementation can be relied upon to provide is a `Foo` implementation. If I decide to provide some enhanced methods, like this:

```
interface EnhancedFoo extends Foo
{
    public void patHeadAndRubBelly();
}

class EnhancedFooImpl implements EnhancedFoo
{
    ... implementation here ...
}

class EnhancedFooFactoryImpl implements FooFactory
{
    @Override public EnhancedFoo getFoo() { return new EnhancedFooImpl(); }
}
```

and the only way my API clients can use the `EnhancedFoo` interface is if they obtain a `Foo` interface and try to cast it as the `EnhancedFoo`.

I remember the way Microsoft handled COM in the [`IUnknown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680509(v=vs.85).aspx) interface:

```
HRESULT QueryInterface(
   [in]   REFIID riid,
   [out]  void **ppvObject
);
```

The idea is that you pass in a GUID for the interface you want, if it succeeds, you get back a pointer that guarantees you can safely cast it to the interface you were looking for.

I could do something similar in a typesafe way with Java:

```
interface FooFactory
{
    public <T extends Foo> T getFoo(Class<T> fooClass);
}
```

where I provide an implementation on request that either returns an instance of the desired subinterface, or returns null if none is available.

My question, is:

- is the QueryInterface pattern reasonable?
- should I just use casting?
- or is the only right way to handle polymorphism in the API to restrict clients to strictly using the plain methods in question? (e.g. the methods in `Foo` in my example and not any `EnhancedFoo` methods)

---

**Clarification:** The factory implementation isn't going to be known by client code. (Let's say it uses dependency injection or some service provider architecture like java's `ServiceLoader` or NetBeans `Lookup`.) So as a client, I don't know what's available. The factory might have access to several `Foo` derivatives and I want the client to be able to request a feature set that it wants, and either it gets that, or it will have to fall back on the base `Foo` functionality.

I guess the hard part for me is that there is runtime dependency here... the pure static typesafe approach where everything is fixed at compile time means that I can only depend on that basic `Foo` functionality. That approach is familiar to me, but then I lose out on possible enhanced features. Whereas the more dynamic / opportunistic approach is something that can take advantage of these features, but I'm not sure of the right way to architect a system that uses it.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply declare your factory with generics and leave the rest as is:

```
static interface FooFactory {
  public <T extends Foo> T getFoo();
}
```

Then thanks to type inference, this will compile:

```
FooFactory f = new EnhancedFooFactoryImpl();
EnhancedFoo e = f.getFoo();
```

(this may not work prior to Java 8)

If the `FooFactory` is not what you expected, the line `EnhancedFoo e = f.getFoo();` will throw a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Type inference has been improved in Java 8.

Comment: Hmm... the exception approach is normal for Python but seems inappropriate for Java.

Comment: I'd say it's perfectly appropriate - better than null-checking

Answer (score 1):

Why not parametrize Factory interface ?

```
static interface FooFactory<T extends Foo> {
    public T getFoo();
}
```

then:

```
class EnhancedFooFactoryImpl implements FooFactory<EnhancedFoo> {

    @Override 
    public EnhancedFoo getFoo() { return new EnhancedFooImpl(); }
}
```

And instantiation:

```
FooFactory<EnhancedFoo> f1 = new EnhancedFooFactoryImpl();
EnhancedFoo foo = f1.getFoo();
```

The enhanced factory of course can be used where base class is expected.

```
FooFactory<?> f2 = new EnhancedFooFactoryImpl();
Foo foo = f2.getFoo();
```

**EDIT (on reply to Your comment)**

If for your design it is better to have parametrized factory method not the factory class then it is a good practice to define it as below:

```
interface FooFactory {

    public <T extends Foo> T getFoo(Class<T> fooClass);
}
```

This gives you advantage in two ways:
1. You can control which actuall clas sa user wants to create.
2. Having a class object you can instantiate it with reflection.

So in this case you do not have to have to special Factory classes for enhanced foo:

```
class FooFactoryImpl implements FooFactory {

    @Override 
    public <T extends Foo> T getFoo(Class<T> c) { 
        try {
            return c.newInstance();
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then usage is like below:

```
FooFactory ff = new FooFactoryImpl();
EnhancedFoo ef = ff.getFoo(EnhancedFoo.class);
Foo f = ff.getFoo(Foo.class);
```

If some Foo implementation requires constructor parameters you can always put corresponding if in the foctory method and instantiate the object "manually":

```
    @Override 
    public <T extends Foo> T getFoo(Class<T> c) { 

        if(SomeParametrizedFoo.class.equals(c)) {
            SomeParamtrizedFoo spf = new SomeParamtrizedFoo("constr arg");
            spf.setParam(16136);
            return (T) spf;
        }

        try {
            return c.newInstance();
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess my thinking is that there are specific capabilities that a client might wish to use. There might be more than one extension available to the `Foo` class, so it's not something I want to leave up to the factory; instead it should be up to the client. I'm inexperienced enough at API design that I'm not 100% sure how to form my question precisely.

Comment: added a clarification

Comment: One note on edit: replace `SomeParametrizedFoo.class.equals(c)` with `c.isAssignableFrom(SomeParametrizedFoo.class)`

Comment: I would vote for `isAssignableFrom` as well; I don't care exactly which class is the implementing class; I *do* care whether it implements/extends the class `c` which is what the client is asking for. And if I want to work with this framework, those concrete classes that implement `c` will provide a compatible constructor.

Comment: I don't see which circumstances would cause us to have a class cast exception here... In fact, now that I think about this, the code in the answer is a bit questionable. A particular instance of factory should produce instance of only one class. The generics are there just for type safety, not to tell the factory what class to produce. @Tomasz Gawel, in your code the factory will produce any class you care to pass in as long as it has a default constructor.

Comment: In your second example, `c` is `SomeFooSubClass`, not `SomeFoo`, so  `c.isAssignableFrom(SomeFoo.class)` is false.